# Rust expects two levels of boxing for generator while I only specified one

Tags: generics, rust, heap-memory, generator

I am encountering a compiler error for something that I feel should work.

I tried [this code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2368732e727c3204ab03d725bc9d29c9&version=nightly&mode=debug) (note generators are nightly-only at the time of writing):

```
#![feature(generators, generator_trait)]

use std::ops::Generator;

struct Value {}

struct Container<G: Generator<Yield = Value, Return = ()>> {
    generator: Box<G>,
}

impl Container<Box<Generator<Yield = Value, Return = ()>>> {
    pub fn new(&mut self) -> Box<Self> {
        let generator: Box<Generator<Yield = Value, Return = ()>> = Box::new(|| loop {
            yield Value {}
        });
        Box::new(Container {
            generator: generator,
        })
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

where I get this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:20:24
   |
20 |             generator: generator,
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::boxed::Box`, found trait std::ops::Generator
   |
   = note: expected type `std::boxed::Box<std::boxed::Box<std::ops::Generator<Yield=Value, Return=()>>>`
              found type `std::boxed::Box<std::ops::Generator<Yield=Value, Return=()>>`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

I don't understand why two levels of boxing are expected here, I only asked for one (`Box<G>`).

It looks like `Generator` is indeed a trait, not an alias for `Box<...>`. I can't think of other explanations.

I can easily resolve the error by replacing `Box<G>` by `G`, but I want to know why my way does not work (could it be a bug?).

*Nightly version 1.28.0-nightly (2018-06-15 967c1f3be1c9ce0469ae) in debug mode on the playground (but I have a similar issue locally with more complex code).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here.

First, you define `Containter<G>` as having a member of type `Box<G>`. Then you write the `impl` for `Containter<Box<G>>`, that naturally has a member of type `Box<Box<G>>`. Probably you just want:

```
impl Container<Generator<Yield = Value, Return = ()>> {
    ...
}
```

Second, if you compile again you have this error:

|

```
16 |         Box::new(Container {
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^ `std::ops::Generator<Yield=Value, Return=()>` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `std::ops::Generator<Yield=Value, Return=()>`
note: required by `Container`
  --> a.rs:7:1
   |
7  | struct Container<G: Generator<Yield = Value, Return = ()>> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This means that `struct Containter` requires that `G` is sized, but your generator  doesn't implement it. That's true, you want `Box<G>` to be a trait object, so `G` will be unsized (a trait type). But type arguments in structs are `Sized` by default. The solution is to add `?Sized` requirement to `Container`:

```
struct Container<G: Generator<Yield = Value, Return = ()> + ?Sized> {
    generator: Box<G>,
}
```

And now it compiles.

**PS**: If your `Container` struct is to be used only with `Generator` trait objects it is far easier to get rid of the generic arguments and just write:

```
struct Container {
    generator: Box<Generator<Yield = Value, Return = ()>>,
}

impl Container {
    pub fn new(&mut self) -> Box<Self> {
        let generator = Box::new(|| loop {
            yield Value {}
        });
        Box::new(Container {
            generator: generator,
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah the extra box was coming from the impl, that makes sense! Also useful ps, thanks.